# Just what is an Eclipse "perspective", and how would I go about making one?

Tags: eclipse

The Eclipse documentation and website are still a bit too thick for me, a total Eclipse noob.  Could someone explain just what a perspective is in terms suitable for non-IDE users, and what is involved in making new perspectives?

So far I'm guessing that a "perspective" is merely a canned arrangement of windows within Eclipse, and that one can choose one of several for e.g.different phases of work on a project.  But I get the impression it's something bigger and more powerful.

Comment: Questions about development tools are off-topic here, but are on-topic on [SO].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've pretty much got it in what you're describing. The thing I would add is that "perspectives" come laid out in a predefined way, but they don't have to stay that way. You can change the window arrangement, add and remove views, etc., and those changes stay with those perspectives.

So, the idea of a perspective, is to allow you to setup a collection of windows and views that works well with your particular workflow, and the way you think.

In Eclipse, go under "Window -> Customize Perspective...", and you'll see a bunch of options for adding/removing things. But don't freak - you can always go back to "Window -> Reset Perspective..." to reset the layout back to the way it was when you first installed Eclipse.

You can also save your current perspective settings/layout by going to "Window -> Save Perspective As...", and save it under an arbitrary name, such as "DarenW's favorite perspective," or whatever you like.

Comment: There are some other, less visible things to it such as key bindings. For instance, the standard debug perspective binds the standard debug stepping keys to editor windows and to the debug window, while the Java persective has them only in the debug window. The idea is always to support a particular specific task, e.g. debugging.