# Eclipse does not return to code view after debugging exit

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I run my code in the debugger in Eclipse, it jumps to the various breakpoints I have set, but when I terminate the debugging session, it does not return me to my previous code editing location.
How can I make it return me to where I was working after a debugging session?

Comment: Whenever you dubug any code the perspective gets changed to dubug so even after the dubug is complete you are still in that mode only so inorder to change the mode just manually change the mode to java or javaee which ever you are using from top right corner in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse there are buttons to select the *[Perspective](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-4.htm)* (eg, Resources, Java, Debug, etc). When you are on Debug, the button Debug is on. If you want to go back to another Perspective, just press the corresponding button.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6650353/639520) and [here](https://eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
It's not possible (out of the box).

An Eclipse bug ticket exists, requesting this feature:
[Bug 46336](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46336)

Alternatively you can easily switch perspectives with:
Ctrl + F8.
See [Shotcuts tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm)

or install a plugin:
[Eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/debug-perspective-auto-closer)