# create a new class do not appear right click menu eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a really annoying problem in Eclipse java neon, when i do a right click on a package in order to create a new class or in any area, Eclipse don't show me proposition like class, package or even project but only a incomplete menu unusable
I have already launch eclipse with -clean but not help

An illustration of the problem, I also notice that Eclipse is in... debug mode ? (upper left corner)
[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are in the Debug Perspective (see [What is a Perspective?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6650354/639520)). You can switch back to the Java or JEE perspective (where most development activities are typically performed) by using the perspective switcher toolbar in the upper-right corner of the Eclipse window.

I suggest you learn about the use of [Perspectives in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-4.htm).

Comment: Thanks !! it's work, 
I had no idea what was perspective

Answer (score 29):

1. Select menu `Window -> Perspective -> Customize Perspective...`.
2. Select `Menu Visibility` tab.
3. Select tree node `File -> New`.
4. Toggle check box of menu items as you like.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it's very untrue that "most development work" takes place outside of debug mode. Java perspective is strictly for reading if I use it at all. Now my debug mode has what it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
File --> New --> (Then choose what you want)
```

Specify the Source folder and package.

Comment: Thanks it work, i can do this without any problem but i want to get back this menu, if you have any idea :
[link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/File:Getting_started_new_java_class.png)

Comment: Assure you are in J2EE order JAVA Perspective and then look that you are in the Package Explorer Window. The context menu has different entries, depending on your window. Other entries come, when you use the Navigator

Answer (score 0):

When I don't find something in the menu there, I just click on `Other...` and search for whatever I want to create. Regardless of the Perspective.

[image]

[image]

Of course it could more practical to customize the Perspective to include the frequently used items as mentioned.